# Countless http requests created in MERN stack application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, fetch, mern

I don't know what does cause this, it sends new request almost every half a second. I was thinking it's because I call my action in render method but it's not, tried to call it in `componentDidMount`, the same result.

Here is the code:

Action:

```
    export const getComments = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ 
    type: GET_COMMENTS
  })
  fetch(`${API_URL}/comments`,
  { method: 'GET', headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    }})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => dispatch({
      type: GET_COMMENTS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data
    }))
    .catch((err) => dispatch({
      type: GET_COMMENTS_FAILED,
      payload: err
    }))
}
```

Since I need post id loaded before I call the comment action I put it in render method:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const { match: { params }, post} = this.props
      this.props.getPost(params.id);
  }


  render() {
    const { post, comments } = this.props;
    {post && this.props.getComments()}
    return <div>
     ...
```

Here is the route:

```
router.get("/comments", (req, res) => {
  Comment.find({})
    .populate("author")
    .exec((err, comments) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      else {
        res.json(comments);
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getComments() function is running during render. The dispatch used in the action is causing a re-render, causing getComments() to fire again, producing an infinite loop.

Instead of fetching comments in the render() function, you should instead fetch them in the componentDidMount lifecycle hook, then in the render function simply display the comments from props;

Answer (score 0):

`getComments()` is invoking the http request, so it should be moved to `componentDidMount` lifecycle hoook.
This should work:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { match: { params } = this.props
      this.props.getPost(params.id);
      this.props.getComments()
  }


  render() {
    const { post, comments } = this.props;
    {post && comments}
    return <div>
     ...
```

When the component has mounted, the params are retrieved from `props.match` and the Post and Comments are fetched. Then with redux, post and comments data is dispatched, and can be accessed in the connected component's `render` method.